# How to insert a vector with different length to a matrix in MATLAB?

Tags: matrix, vector

How to insert a vector with different length to a matrix? For example I have a randomly located nodes=10; After that I am finding who are the neighbours of this nodes for example for node: i = 2 neighbours are nodes: j = 5 and 6, so the vector which containts this value is neighb_i = [neighb_i j]; but maybe I have to add some zeros to fill the vector till the length of a matrix ( in this case nodes are 10, so the matrix will be 10x10 ) But I want to keep all the values of neighbours for all nodes in a matrix, because when I am using a vector after the next interation this value is replacing themselves so at the next iteration when i = 3 I don't have information about when i = 2. How can I store this in a matrix, which has length nodes x nodes ?

```
close all
clear all
clc

x = 2000;  %m

y = 2000;  %m

nodes = 8; 




%% Random location and direction, calculating the distance;

loc_x = x*rand(1,nodes)

loc_y = y*rand(1,nodes)

loc = [loc_x' loc_y']

dist(loc_x);

dist(loc_y);

distance = sqrt(dist(loc_x).^2 + dist(loc_y).^2)   % = dist(loc')

distance(1:nodes+1:nodes^2) = inf;  % replace zero diagonal with infinity 


%% Power:



noise_power_dBm = -90; %dBm 

noise_power_w = 10^((noise_power_dBm - 30)/10); % W

% The channel is based on a path-loss model in which  is distance between    nodes i and j 
% and 3 - is attenuation exponent considerd as 3 ( 1:6 ) 

channel_gain = (1)./(distance).^3;   %dB

channel_gain(1:nodes+1:nodes^2) = inf;  % replace zero diagonal with infinity


min_SNR_dB = 10; %dB, minimum required SNR at the receiving nodes

min_SNR = 10^(min_SNR_dB/10);

p_max_dBm = 10;   % dBm

p_max_w = 10^((p_max_dBm - 30)/10);  % W


p_uni = (min_SNR*noise_power_w)./(channel_gain); % unicast power between two nodes

p_uni(1:nodes+1:nodes^2) = inf;  % replace zero diagonal with infinity 

plot(loc_x,loc_y,'r*'); 



change = 1;

cost = inf(1,nodes)   % at the beginning cost of all nodes are infinity 

cost(1) = 0;          % except the cost of node 1 = 0 ( source node ) 

while change == 1   % change is when a child chooses parent node and change its parent node; if its a =1 its go again in for loops 

change = 0;     % when i am coming inside while loop I change the change parameter to 0 and if some changes occurse 


for i = 2:nodes %i - child node   first i = 2, then j is 1,2,3...8 it checks all the nodes starts from 1 because source node can be a neighbour of other node

neighb_i = [];

for j = 1:nodes  % j - parent node  

if p_uni(i,j) < p_max_w 

   neighb_i = [neighb_i j];  %Found who are the neighbours  ; to use a matrix not a vector ????????

end
% calculate the cost for every nodes First Dijkstra, later MC 
% and choose the parent node for every node ; if we have some changes
% ---> change = 1

for k = [neighb_i j] % neighb_i

% cost(i,k) = 1:nodes;


end
end
keyboard
end
% At the end of this while - I have to know what is the parent node for
% every node and when I come out I can draw a graph.
end


%%
gplot(nodes,loc)

%plot(source,'b*');
plot(loc_x,loc_y,'rO');
axis([x y x y]);

hold on;
grid on;
grid on, xlabel('x'), ylabel('y');
title('Random nodes');
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you've tried? Have you preallocated your adjacency matrix? Are you attempting to grow the matrix as you go? It's hard to follow exactly what you're trying to do, so examples would probably help.

Comment: This is my code ( I have edited my post ) ,
 neighb_i = [neighb_i j]; %Found who are the neighbours ; 
 I have to put this values into e matrix after all iteration ( in this example number of nodes are 8 , so I would have 8 x 8 matrix, but the problem is that this vector has a at each iteration different values so I don't know how to store them in a matrix. Thank you a lot fo the help.

Comment: I think it would be better to simplify your code to an example that only shows the problem you're having (see [mcve] for tips). Otherwise it might take people a while to read and understand your full program. But I'm going to take a wild guess and say that `j` is a vector and you want it to be a new row in the matrix `neighb_i`, is that right? If so, then you just need to add a semicolon between `neighb_i` and `j` like: `neighb_i = [neighb_i; j];`.

Comment: I am quite new at Matlab, so I don't know what can I remove or what not so I decide to post all the code.
 Maybe I should try to explain again what exactly I am trying to explain. For example, if we have 10 randomly located nodes and we have to find which of these nodes are neighbours and which are not. After that I have to collect this result in a matrix. If we assumed that the neighbours after running this code are:

Comment: The neighbours of node 1 are nodes 3 and 4 
The neighbours of node 2 is only node 1 
The neighbours of node 3 are nodes 3, 8 and 10 and so on.
 My question was how to collect all the information about the neighbours in a matrix which will have a vectors with different lengths. And the matrix would be 10x10 because of the nodes .My code works but it cannot store this values after each iterations, so I need to collect the results in a matrix. Do I have to fill all the missing values with zeros till the length become the same like the dimension of the matrix

Thank you a lot!

Comment: Please add clarifications as edits to your original question. They're easier to read there and not as likely to go away. As for storing the results, you can either fill in all of the zeros or you can use a cell array with vectors of unequal length.